# Qt: Signal Slot not working

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qt-signals

I am trying to implement Signal and Slot system between the main gui and another object moved to another thread...the following is how the class design looks like...unfortunately cannot implement it...

**MainWindow.h**

```
signals:
    void StopDisplayWidget();
    void StartDisplayWidget();
    void signalFromGUI();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_start_display_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_stop_display_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_check_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    displaythread *threadforDisplay;
    display *displayWidget;
    QThread *WorkerDisplay;
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
{
    threadforDisplay = new displaythread;
    threadforDisplay->setptr2display(displayWidget);

    WorkerDisplay = new QThread;
    QObject::connect(WorkerDisplay,SIGNAL(started()),threadforDisplay,SLOT(Process()));

    QObject::connect(this,SIGNAL(StartDisplayWidget()),threadforDisplay,SLOT(StartDisplay()));
    QObject::connect(this,SIGNAL(StopDisplayWidget()),threadforDisplay,SLOT(StopDisplay()));
    QObject::connect(this,SIGNAL(signalFromGUI()),threadforDisplay,SLOT(Check()));

    threadforDisplay->moveToThread(WorkerDisplay);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_start_display_clicked()
{
    if(!threadforDisplay->IsDisplayActive())
        emit this->StartDisplayWidget();

    if(!WorkerDisplay->isRunning())
        WorkerDisplay->start();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_stop_display_clicked()
{
    if(threadforDisplay->IsDisplayActive())
    {
        emit this->StopDisplayWidget();
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_check_clicked()
{
    std::cout<<"CHECKING SIGNAL SLOT"<<std::endl;
    emit this->signalFromGUI();
}
```

**threadforDisplay** is a pointer to **displaythread class** which looks like

**displaythread.h**

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QWaitCondition>
#include <QMutex>
#include "display.h"

class displaythread : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit displaythread(QObject *parent = 0);
    bool IsDisplayActive() const;
    void setptr2display(display *);

signals:

public slots:
    void Process();
    void StartDisplay();
    void StopDisplay();
    void Check();


private:
    void SleepThread();

    volatile bool stopped,running;
    QMutex mutex;
    QWaitCondition waitcondition;
    display *displayinGUI;
```

**displaythread.cpp**

```
void displaythread::setptr2display(display *ptr)
{
    displayinGUI = ptr;
}

void displaythread::Process()
{
    std::cout<<"RECEIVED START PROCESS SIGNAL"<<std::endl;
    running = true;
    while(true)
    {
        if(!stopped)
        {
            displayinGUI->update();
            this->SleepThread();
        }
    }

}

void displaythread::SleepThread()
{
    mutex.lock();
    waitcondition.wait(&mutex,20);
    mutex.unlock();
}

void displaythread::StartDisplay()
{
    std::cout<<"RECEIVED START SIGNAL"<<std::endl;
    stopped = false;
    running = true;
}

void displaythread::StopDisplay()
{
    std::cout<<"RECEIVED STOP SIGNAL"<<std::endl;
    stopped = true;
    running = false;
}

bool displaythread::IsDisplayActive() const
{
    return running;
}

void displaythread::Check()
{
    std::cout<<"SIGNAL FROM GUI RECEIVED"<<std::endl;
}
```

**display.h**

```
class display : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit display(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~display();

signals:

public slots:

private:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);

    IplImage *image_opencvBGR,*image_opencvRGB;
    QImage image;
    CvCapture *webcam;
```

**display.cpp**

```
display::display(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    image_opencvRGB = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640,480),8,3);
    webcam = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);
}

display::~display()
{
    cvReleaseCapture(&webcam);
}

void display::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    //std::cout<<"IN PAINT LOOP"<<std::endl;
    image_opencvBGR = cvQueryFrame(webcam);

    cvCvtColor(image_opencvBGR,image_opencvRGB,CV_BGR2RGB);
    image = QImage((const unsigned char*)image_opencvRGB->imageData,image_opencvRGB->width,image_opencvRGB->height,QImage::Format_RGB888);
    QRectF target(0.0,0.0,image.width(),image.height());
    QRectF source(0.0,0.0,image.width(),image.height());
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawImage(target,image,source);
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

RECEIVED START PROCESS SIGNAL

However except the Process slot no other slot is working when signals are emitted from the main gui i.e. MainWindow..is it due to movetoThread command? Donno where i am going wrong..

Comment: what is `display *displayinGUI;` I meant what is the type\class `display`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simple : Qwidgets don't work outside the main thread. So you cannot execute GUI code using `displaythread`.

Furthermore your while loop may cause issues (I know the variable is volatile but I dont have the time to analyze properly if it is correct)

See the [documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/main-snapshot/threads-qobject.html#qobject-reentrancy) for more information.

ps: It seems you are overdoing things. Rework your whole design. GUI operations are in the main thread. Use threads for computations only. If the communication between thread and access to their variables use signal and slots only, you dont need locking mechanisms.

Comment: i am trying to stream images from a webcam...i want image streaming in a different thread than the GUI...

Comment: you need to put all the code which get the data and create the cv image, or QImage in a separate thread. The widget which render is in the main thread (ie don't move it). When an image is ready you use a qt signal\slot to transmit the image between threads. If you dont see how it is done ask a different question (because it is), post the link here and I will try to reply

Comment: k...gt u....will pass the pointer to the image through signal slot...coz passing the whole image wont be a good idea...

Comment: try passing `QSharedPointer`